# Grabbing web data using C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking to make a program that pulls how much karma a user has on Reddit by typing their name. Basically I'm just wondering how I can get values from a web server using a program I made
Where should I start?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Comment: You should start by doing some independent research, then posting a question here when you get stuck writing actual code.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please try to add some code that shows where you are and illustrates more specifically the problem you are having.

Comment: Too broad... search term is "web crawler" (but first check out link by @SystemDown).

Answer (score 1):

> **Where should I start?**

Reddit has an API documented at http://www.reddit.com/dev/api.  The API exposes a method for returning user information:

> GET /user/username/about.json
>
> Return information about the user, including karma and gold status.

For demonstration, you can construct a query using a web browser directly, e.g., by accessing http://www.reddit.com/user/[username]/about.json.  The results are returned in JSON format, and include link and comment karma as separate elements:

```
{"kind": "t2", 
 [some data omitted],
 "link_karma": 1764, "comment_karma": 42,
 [more data omitted]
}
```

You can access the JSON directly via a HTTP get request, or use a wrapper class (several are listed [here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers), including one for C#).  As with any API, you should read the [conditions of use](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API) before making use of the service.